# How can I use zoom in libgdx-InputProcess?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have to use touchUp system so I can't use GestureListener/Detector, and I already make source by using InputProcess.

And now, I need Zoom in-out System.
how can I use zoom in/out system in libgdx-InputProcess?

Answer (score 1):

**GestureDetector** comes up with a zoom function :

```
@Override
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) 
{
    // This will resize sprite to new distance
    sprite.setSize(distance,distance);
    return true;
}
```

Whole tutorial AND video [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/16/LibGDX-Video-Tutorial-Gestures-Panning-Zooming-Pinch-Tapping-and-more.aspx).